# Auto rescale for mobile web browser

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to allow the photo and table to be able to resize based on the web browser size on mobile phone. You may refer to picture 1 which is the UI of laptop web browser, photo 2 and 3 shows the UI of mobile web browser. I've included  but it seems that this only work on the input because the icon on the right corner and the table are still out of alignment.

Style

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Responsive Admin Dashboard Template" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="admin,dashboard" />
        <meta name="author" content="Steelcoders" />

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/materialize/css/materialize.min.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/plugins/material-preloader/css/materialPreloader.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="assets/css/alpha.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

       
        <style>
            .errorWrap {
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0 0 20px 0;
                background: #fff;
                border-left: 4px solid #dd3d36;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
            }

            .succWrap {
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0 0 20px 0;
                background: #fff;
                border-left: 4px solid #5cb85c;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
            }
            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            
            .tableTitle {
                background: rgb(19,100,181);
                color: white;
            }
            
            .tableBody {
                border:none !important;
                margin-top:-75px !important;
                margin-bottom:-105px !important;
            }
            .topcorner{
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                right:0;
                max-height: 20vh;
            }

/* @media(max-width:600px){
    .topcorner{
        width: 100% !important;
    }
} */

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  .topcorner{
    width: 100%;
  }
}

          
        </style>
```

Table

```
<div id="topcorner">
   <img src="profile-image.png" class="topcorner" width="20%" height="15%"/>
</div>
<div>
<center><h3>JOB APPLICATION FORM</h3><center> 
<section>
<div class="wizard-content">
<?php if ($error) { ?><div class="errorWrap"><strong>ERROR</strong>:<?php echo htmlentities($error); ?> </div><?php } else if ($msg) { ?><div class="succWrap"><strong>SUCCESS</strong>:<?php echo htmlentities($msg); ?> </div><?php } ?>
                                       

<div class="input-field col s12">
    <label for="applicant">Full Name</label>
    <input id="applicant" name="applicant" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
                                                
<div class="input-field col s12">
   <label for="label_position">Position Interested</label>
   <input type="text" id="position" name="position" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
   <label for="phone">Phone</label>
   <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
 <label for="email">Email Address</label>
 <input name="email" type="email" id="email" onBlur="checkAvailabilityEmailid(1)" autocomplete="off" required>
  <div style="margin-top:-20px; margin-bottom:5px;"><span id="emailIdAvailability" style="font-size:12px;"></span></div>
 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <label for="dateAva">Date Available / Notice Period</label>
  <input id="dateAva" name="dateAva" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <label for="course">Course</label>
    <input id="course" name="course" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>

<table style="margin-top:25px;margin-bottom:25px;">
    <tr class="tableTitle">
            <th><center>Upload Resume</th>
    </tr>

<td><input style="margin-left:600px;" class="tableBody" type="file" id="resume1" name="resume1" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.png,.jpeg"></td> 

</tr>
</table>
```

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lACgB.png)
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyDGR.png)

Comment: Try to completely ship the HTML with no style-sheet information. Especially for browsers which are able to render different fonts, they do a very decent job to make use of the view-port already. Then add style peu-a-peu until the result pleases you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to scale both up and down on responsiveness, set the CSS width property to 100% and height to auto:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

If you want an image to scale down if it has to, but never scale up to be larger than its original size, use max-width: 100%:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If you want to restrict a responsive image to a maximum size, use the max-width property, with a pixel value of your choice:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

To create a responsive table, add a container element with overflow-x:auto around the :

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

if you use bootstrap ( like bootstrap 3), you can easily define the class `.table-responsive` for having a responsive table.

Comment: Hi , it doesn't work for me when i open up the webpage using my phone web browser

Comment: hi. do you use developer tools?
if no, press Ctrl+Shift+I to open it and then enable toggle device toolbar by pressing Ctrl+Shift+M or you can also find it next to the "Element" tab on the top left of your developer tools. by enabling it, you can change the size of your browser easily and see if it's working in smaller devices ( like mobiles or tablets) or not. please let me know if it's still not working.